# C# ASP.Net : Get Custom Attribute of Hidden from Request.Form

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, request, hidden

I have some code which is rendering some custom attributes of Hidden Control (without runat=server).

Something like,

And I have a lot of these hidden elements on my form.

When I submit the form, I am looping through a set of ids, say 1200 to 1250, so I will read controls based on that, and also hidden with Request.Form["hdn "]

Now problem is, as we know we get value attribute from form when we do Request.Form["id"] for hidden, I want to read my custom attributes from hidden element. Is there any way? Note that, I can not touch the rendering part here.

Thanks.

Jimmy.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is going to work - if you're dealing with plain HTML controls (i.e. ones without the `runat="server"` attribute), then when they're posted in a form, all you get is a load of key-value pairs, corresponding to elements' IDs and their Values.

When you do `Request.Form["id"]`, you're not getting the element, you're just getting the *value* of that element (i.e. whatever was in the element's `value` attribute). There's no way to get access to the contents of any other attributes, custom or otherwise.

You'll either need to add the `runat="server"` attribute to these controls and then pick them up in a postback, or use some crazy javascript to pick out the custom attribute values and stick them in the form id/value collection somehow.

Comment: Graham,

Thanks for the answer.
As I said it is not possible for me to change rendering code. Actually I too thought the same, that with this rendering only way is to have some javascript which concates all my custom attributes to value of that hidden element.

I would still love to have some way (better way) out of this.

Thanks,
Jimmy.